# figuring out if an apostrophe is a quote or contraction

Tags: arrays, ruby, nlp, enumeration

I am looking for a way to go through a sentence to see if an apostrophe is a quote or a contraction so I can remove punctuation from the string, and then normalize all words.

My test sentence is: `don't frazzel the horses. 'she said wow'.`

In my attempts I have split the sentence into words parts tokonizing on words and non words like so:

```
contractionEndings = ["d", "l", "ll", "m", "re", "s", "t", "ve"]

sentence = "don't frazzel the horses. 'she said wow'.".split(/(\w+)|(\W+)/i).reject! { |word| word.empty? }
```

This returns `["don", "'", "t", " ", "frazzel", " ", "the", " ", "horses", ". '", "she", " ", "said", " ", "wow", "'."]`

Next I want to be able to iterate sentence looking for apostrophes `'` and when one is found, compare the next element to see if it is included in the `contractionEndings` array. If it is included I want to join the prefix, the apostrophe `'`, and the suffix into one index, else remove the apostrophes.

In this example, `don`, `'`, and `t` would be joined into `don't` as a single index, but `. '` and `'.` would be removed.

Afterwards I can run a regex to remove other punctuation from the sentence so that I can pass it into my stemmer to normalize the input.

The final output I am after is `don't frazzel the horses she said wow` in which all punctuation will be removed besides apostrophes for contractions.

If anyone has any suggestions to make this work or have a better idea on how to solve this problem I would like to know.

Overall I want to remove all punctuation from the sentence except for contractions.

Thanks

Comment: what result you expect finally?

Comment: @Ilya `don't frazzel the horses she said wow`

Comment: Why the rush to select an answer? Why not wait at least until those working on answers have had a chance to post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
irb:0> s = "don't frazzel the horses. 'she said wow'."
irb:0> contractionEndings = ["d", "l", "ll", "m", "re", "s", "t", "ve"]
irb:0> s.scan(/\w+(?:'(?:#{contractionEndings.join('|')}))?/)
=> ["don't", "frazzel", "the", "horses", "she", "said", "wow"]
```

The regex scans for some "word" characters, and then optionally (with the `?`) an apostrophe-plus-contraction ending. You can subsitute in Ruby expressions just like double-quote strings do, so we can get our contractions in, joining them with the regex alternation operator `|`. The last thing is to mark the groups (sections in parentheses) as non-capturing with `?:` so that scan doesn't return a bunch of `nil`s, just the whole match per-iteration.

Or maybe you don't need the list of explicit abbreviation endings with this method. I also fixed other problematic constructions, thanks to Cary.

```
irb:0> "don't -frazzel's the jack-o'-lantern's handle, ma'am- 'she said hey-ho'.".scan(/\w[-'\w]*\w(?:'\w+)?/)
=> ["don't", "frazzel's", "the", "jack-o'-lantern's", "handle", "ma'am", "she", "said", "hey-ho"]
```

Comment: And there we have it, regex to the rescue once again. For future readers do you mind expanding on this answer, specifically what the regex is doing.

Comment: Added another method.

Comment: The second method is problematic in that it ignores non-word characters. For example, `"don't frazzel the horses; she said: 'wow!'.".scan(/\w+(?:'\w+)?/).join(' ') #=> "don't frazzel the horses she said wow"`.

Comment: What about "o'clock", "ma'am", "ne'er-do-well", "jack-o'-lantern" and many others that do not have an ending in `contractionEndings`? Trying to list all possible endings is surely futile. Also "Chris' cat has fleas." becomes "Chris cat has fleas."

Comment: If you're passing the words into a stemmer and normaliser (for indexing?), you surely want to ignore non-word characters? I offered the second because indeed it's a bit ambitious to list all the possible after-`'` endings. But you're right, there's some formations I missed – I've updated the pattern and test to cope.

Comment: I missed "...and then normalize all words", whatever that means.

Comment: You should not create a regexp on runtime using variables, if performance is an issue. This should be an anti-pattern! It's better to precompile and store it e.g. in a constant, if it's not going to change like in this case.

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in a comment, I think trying to list all possible contraction endings is fruitless. In fact, some contractions, such as "couldn’t’ve", contain more than one apostrophe.

The other option is to match single quotes. My first thought was to remove the character `"'"` if is at the start of the sentence or after a space, or if it is followed by a space or is at the end of a sentence. Unfortunately, that approach is frustrated by possessive words that end in an "s": "Chris' cat has fleas". Even worse, how are we to interpret "Where are 'Chris' cars'?" or "'Twas the 'night before Christmas'."?

Here is a way to remove single quotes when there are no apostrophes at the beginning or ends of words (which, admittedly, is of questionable value).

```
r = /
    (?<=\A|\s) # match the beginning of the string or a whitespace char in a
               # positive lookbehind
    \'         # match a single quote
    |          # or 
    \'         # match a single quote
    (?=\s|\z)  # match a whitespace char or the end of the string in a
               # positive lookahead
    /x         # free-spacing regex definition mode

"don't frazzel the horses. 'she said wow'".gsub(r,'')
  #=> "don't frazzel the horses. she said wow"
```

I think the best solution is for the English language to use different symbols for apostrophes and single quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Usually the apostrophe will stay with the contraction after tokenzation.

Try a normal NLP tokenizer, e.g. in python `nltk`:

```
>>> from nltk import word_tokenize
>>> word_tokenize("don't frazzel the horses")
['do', "n't", 'frazzel', 'the', 'horses']
```

For multiple sentences:

```
>>> from string import punctuation
>>> from nltk import sent_tokenize, word_tokenize
>>> text = "don't frazzel the horses. 'she said wow'."
>>> sents = sent_tokenize(text)
>>> sents
["don't frazzel the horses.", "'she said wow'."]
>>> [word for word in word_tokenize(sents[0]) if word not in punctuation]
['do', "n't", 'frazzel', 'the', 'horses']
>>> [word for word in word_tokenize(sents[1]) if word not in punctuation]
["'she", 'said', 'wow']
```

Flattening the sentences before `word_tokenize`:

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> sents
["don't frazzel the horses.", "'she said wow'."]
>>> [word_tokenize(sent) for sent in sents]
[['do', "n't", 'frazzel', 'the', 'horses', '.'], ["'she", 'said', 'wow', "'", '.']]
>>> list(chain(*[word_tokenize(sent) for sent in sents]))
['do', "n't", 'frazzel', 'the', 'horses', '.', "'she", 'said', 'wow', "'", '.']
>>> [word for word in list(chain(*[word_tokenize(sent) for sent in sents])) if word not in punctuation]
['do', "n't", 'frazzel', 'the', 'horses', "'she", 'said', 'wow']
```

Note that the single quote stays with the `'she`. Sadly, simple task of tokenization still has its weakness amidst all the hype on sophisticated (deep) machine learning methods today =(

It makes mistakes even with formal grammatical text:

```
>>> text = "Don't frazzel the horses. 'She said wow'."
>>> sents = sent_tokenize(text)
>>> sents
["Don't frazzel the horses.", "'She said wow'."]
>>> [word_tokenize(sent) for sent in sents]
[['Do', "n't", 'frazzel', 'the', 'horses', '.'], ["'She", 'said', 'wow', "'", '.']]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [Pragmatic Tokenizer gem](https://github.com/diasks2/pragmatic_tokenizer). It can detect [English contractions](https://github.com/diasks2/pragmatic_tokenizer/blob/master/lib/pragmatic_tokenizer/languages/english.rb#L10-L97).

```
s = "don't frazzel the horses. 'she said wow'."
PragmaticTokenizer::Tokenizer.new(punctuation: :none).tokenize(s)
=> ["don't", "frazzel", "the", "horses", "she", "said", "wow"]

s = "'Twas the 'night before Christmas'."
PragmaticTokenizer::Tokenizer.new(punctuation: :none).tokenize(s)
=> ["'twas", "the", "night", "before", "christmas"]

s = "He couldn’t’ve been right."
PragmaticTokenizer::Tokenizer.new(punctuation: :none).tokenize(s)
=> ["he", "couldn’t’ve", "been", "right"]
```

Comment: PS - Pragmatic Tokenizer also has an [expand contractions](https://github.com/diasks2/pragmatic_tokenizer#expand_contractions) option.